# Getting vbScript do something only on a whole number division

Tags: vba

I am trying to get VBA to click F11 for me, if a process has occurred 8x

```
    Do While y<Entries
    InitialCopy
    
    If y/8 Then <---- **PROBLEM AREA**
     autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
     autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf11]"
    End If
    y=y+1
    Loop
```

So I need to tell it to only hit the Then portion if y/8 generates a whole number in the arithmetic, not in the way vba sees it (ie. only integer portion). Any ideas are welcomed.

Then should only execute on the variable equaling 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 in an underlying division arithmetic output. NOT in a VBA / operator output

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution is

```
Do While y<Entries
InitialCopy

If y Mod 8 = 0 Then 
 autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
 autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf11]"
End If
y=y+1
Loop
```